# PHP - Using a while loop to create a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I want to make an array like this

```
$array = array("'firstName1', 'lastName1'", "'firstName2', 'lastName2'", ......);
```

I always get an error like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\Tests\index.php on line 11

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
    $x=1;
    $a = array(
    while($x<=10):
    "'firstName$x', 'lastName$x'"; //I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO IN THIS LINE//
    $x++;
    endwhile;
    );
    print_r($a);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="number" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['number'];$i++){
    echo "<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='firstName$i' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lastName$i' /></td>
    </tr>";
    }
    $i-=1;
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='hide' value='$i' />";
    }           
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="reg"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$a = array();

while($x<=10):
    $a[] = 'firstName'.$x;
    $a[] = 'lastName'.$x;
    $x++;
endwhile;
```

I read your question again, if you want this "'firstName1', 'lastName1'" to be actually a string then,

```
$a = array();
while($x<=10):
    $a[] = 'firstName'.$x.'lastName'.$x;
    $x++;
endwhile;
```

Or based on your question title (nested array) then,

```
$x = 1;
while($x<=10):
   $a[] = array('firstName'.$x, 'lastName'.$x);
   $x++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: No need to declare the array first. You're doing that with the short syntax.

Comment: thank you so much.. this is exactly what I need.. but what if I want to make it like this $a[] = "'$_POST[firstName$x]', '$_POST[lastName$x]'"; <br/> and the output would be like this ('Kevin Steve', 'Maningo')

Comment: use this $a[] = $_POST["firstName".$x].", ".$_POST["lastName".$x];

Comment: Thank you, its done. I made it like this `$a[] = "'".$_POST["firstName".$x].", ".$_POST["lastName".$x]."'";` and it works as I want it too.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

May this help you.

```
$x = 1;
while($x <=10 ):    
    $a[] = '"\'firstName'.$x.'\', \'lastName'.$x.'\'"';    
    $x++;
endwhile;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => "'firstName1', 'lastName1'"
    [1] => "'firstName2', 'lastName2'"
    [2] => "'firstName3', 'lastName3'"
    [3] => "'firstName4', 'lastName4'"
    [4] => "'firstName5', 'lastName5'"
    [5] => "'firstName6', 'lastName6'"
    [6] => "'firstName7', 'lastName7'"
    [7] => "'firstName8', 'lastName8'"
    [8] => "'firstName9', 'lastName9'"
    [9] => "'firstName10', 'lastName10'"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
$x=1;
$a = array();
while($x<=10){
 $a[] = "firstName$x";
 $a[] = "lastName$x";
 $x++;
}

print_r($a);
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure using double quotes quite qualifies for a duplicate answer since the variable expansion is not improving anything over concatenation.

Comment: @RobB, well, I got some times error when I used the variable in single quotes as used by the asker :) , I think it is best practice to use the variables in double quotes rather than single quotes.